# Is there an easy way to create a 100% folder-only Dialog?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm just wondering if there is a way to display this Dialog in java? I know that there are DirectoryChooser objects, but I want to know if there's a way to display this specific Dialog and if not why?

[image: Dialog Image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html) "These dialogs have look and feel of the platform UI components which is independent of JavaFX."

Which dialog you get is dependent on the platform and version you are running on and it is generally out of your control.

You would have to independently recreate the dialog from the ground up to get it to look the same on every platform and version.